# Excluding a column on insert

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Is there any way that you can specify in Fluent NHibernate to leave out a column whenever it inserts a record if the objects property is null or some other specific value?  Coincidentally the column I want to leave out is a Reference in my mapping.  Here is my scenario:

```
public class OrderLineMap : ClassMap<OrderLine>
{
    public OrderLineMap()
    {
        Table("ORDER_LINE");
        Id(x => x.Id, "ORDER_LINE_ID");

        //USER_ID is a GUID.  Column default in DB is Guid.Empty
        References(x => x.User, "USER_ID").Cascade.SaveUpdate();
    }
}
```

I have an OrderLine that has a reference to a User but this reference is not necessarily present at the time we create the order.  It can be updated at a later date and time.  Since there is a foreign key relationship here there is a column default of GUID.Empty that would handle an insert without specifying this column.  There is also an "Empty" user in the Users table.

Currently I am finding this "Empty" user in the database and setting my OrderLine object's User reference to this instance.  This way seems kind of clumsy to me and I was looking for a better way to do it.  I have several relationships like this in my db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the USER_ID column of the ORDER_LINE table does not allow nulls, you're probably stuck with your current setup. If it does allow nulls then you should set the type of the User property to be Guid? and make sure it is set to null before you save the OrderLine class. That way the column value is set to null in the database and it won't require an "Empty" row in the Users table to enforce the referential integrity.

Comment: The column in question does not allow nulls but this database is in the design phase so I may bring this up to our db designer to just leave this column as nullable.  I guess I didn't realize you could make a column nullable if there was a foreign key constraint on that column.  Thanks for your help.